# Does it make sense to have maxBufferPoolSize smaller than maxBufferSize?

Tags: .net, wcf

Does it make sense to have the maxBufferPoolSize value smaller than maxBufferSize? From my understanding the answer is 'No'. However the [*true* explanation of these values](http://obsessivelycurious.blogspot.com/2008/04/wcf-memory-buffer-management.html) from within the .NET Framework's BufferManager class is a bit low-level and a little confusing.

Odd thing is for large message tests, I can up just the 'maxBufferSize' value to a larger number than the 'maxBufferPoolSize' value and it works. I would think if I did not allocate a large enough pool (maxBufferPoolSize), for the largest allocated buffer (maxBufferSize) it would fail, but apparently this is not the case.

Can anyone explain or answer this please? Thanks!

Comment: I think your understanding is correct and it doesn't make sense conceptually. The fact that it otherwise works shouldn't deter you from using values that make sense to you. Perhaps you can ask the WCF team for an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a message's life is complete, we try to return the buffer that was used to hold. WCF will successfully return the buffer if the total memory held by the pool on return will be <= MaxBufferPoolSize.

Similarly when creating/receiving a message WCF tries to take a buffer from the pool and if the pool does not have a buffer of that size then we allocate using GC. The Max size for allocation in buffered mode is guarded by MaxReceivedMessage size.

You can check the memory usage of your app and see GC performance counters and you will see that there will be lot of time in GC allocating and collecting because WCF will not be able to pool these buffers.

Hope this was helpful.